# Settings for Taulman 618 Nylon

Tags: filament, nylon

I would like to know what are the best settings for Taulman 618 Nylon filament? In particular, the print head and print bed temperatures.

Comment: Best for what? These things depend on a lot of variables (like your printer, print speed, layer height, etc...).

Comment: Hi Cynthia, and welcome to Stack Exchange - 3D Printing. Please could you expand your answer, with more detail, as Tom has requested in [his comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/settings-for-taulman-618-nylon#comment5475_3980). The more information that you provide the more likely it is that someone will be able to provide you with an accurate answer. Also, take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

240°C, lots of cooling.

See [Material Specification Print Sheet - Taulmann 618 Nylon](http://www.hyrel3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MSPS-Nylon.pdf).

Comment: Note: sometimes, for Nylon, I tape some fine sandpaper, grit up, and print on that. This gives more texture for the Nylon to adhere to.